# Getting a 421 error

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client

I'm trying to download a file from a public ftp server. Here is my c# source code:

```
        FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://ftp.exotic-guild.de/test.exe")) as FtpWebRequest;


        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous@exotic-guild.de", "");
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
        System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close(); //Closes the connection to the server
```

Here is the linke to the documentation from the public_ftp server: [wolkenbauer anonymus ftp documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Anonymous+FTP#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ftp.exe ftp.exotic-guild.de` the response is:

> 421 Sorry, cleartext sessions and weak ciphers are not accepted on this server.
>   Please reconnect using SSL/TLS security mechanisms.
>   Connection closed by remote host.

So add:

```
request.EnableSsl = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

The second line bypasses certificate validation because the certificate served is invalid for some reason (you may like to investigate).

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure